# Magento not upgrading from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.1

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

I created a copy of my site on xammp as a Development version to test the upgrade from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.1 . But when I went forth and carried out the upgrade, I got no errors although going to magento connect my version shows 1.9.2.4. Looking at core_resources table the data_version numbers match 1.9.2.4. So looks like a failed upgrade.

I used the method of replacing the app > core folder with the new one. And the frontend base default folder, Then mage.php file with new one. From here I deleted local.xml and went through installation. Could you guys help with what is the best way to upgrade and where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select all file from fresh 1.9.3.1 magento and paste it to your site.
clear cashe ans session from var.

your site is upgrade to 1.9.3.1

Comment: Have done. Shall re-test again once dev database is re-backed.

Comment: ok. If above answer will help you, please accept it, So it will help other in community.